# Enumerable Range make it count every 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to make it counts every 5 (5,10,15,20 etc)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StartMinute, Enumerable.Range(1, 60).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }), "Minute", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you need to add where condition which will select only those numbers which are divisible by 5.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StartMinute, Enumerable.Range(1, 60).Where(x => x%5 == 0).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }), "Minute", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating *all* numbers and skipping the numbers you don't want, you could generate just the numbers needed:

```
 Enumerable.Range(0,12).Select(n => 5*n)
```

This will generate 0, 5, 10, ..,  55

Or use `.Range(1,12)` to count from 5 to 60.